# React Native 0.60.0 & 0.60.x Android For animated GIF support

Tags: android, react-native, fresco

In latest version of React Native 0.60.x animated GIF is not working I am using following fresco version.

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.10.0'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.10.0'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use following it works for me for RN v0.60.3

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'
```

Comment: I used this version on a branch and fixed it, but no on a different branch I implemented this and its still not animating gif.

Answer (score 2):

Change the version to `2.0.0`

```
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'
```

You don't need to use  `compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.10.0'`

EDIT.

On my project compile is still working, but changing it to implementation isn't giving any issue so you are good to go!

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'
```

Comment: It gives warning `compile` is deprecated so `implementation` is required

Comment: change compile to implementation